# While loop issue in Java

Tags: java

This is a little bit of my code.

```
System.out.print("Would you like to continue (Y/N)?");
while (!Anwser.equals("Y")){
    Anwser = UserInput.next();
    System.out.println("Would you like to continue (Y/N)?");
}
```

This is the answer.

```
> Would you like to continue (Y/N)? 
> Would you like to continue (Y/N)?
```

Why does it print it out again although I typed Y and the conditions were not met? After this it continues with the code:

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `while` loop is done zero or more times.

A `do while` loop is done one or more times.

For a continuation question you do not really care what the user inputs as long as it is a 'Y' or 'y'.
Anything else will terminate the program.
Also with a continuation question the program usually wants to run once. So wrap your code in a `do while` loop.

```
do {
// Your code goes here

    System.out.print("Would you like to continue (Y/N)?");
    Anwser = UserInput.next();
} while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase( "Y"));
```

As to why your code does not work. Perhaps you should have assigned a value to Answer before the loop starts.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the value of "Anwser" variable and replace it with the user's input

like this:

```
System.out.print("Would you like to continue (Y/N)?");
Anwser = UserInput.next();
while (!Anwser.equals("Y")){
    System.out.println("Would you like to continue (Y/N)?");
    Anwser = UserInput.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is printing twice is because the first line is printing the question outside of the loop, then tests the answer (which was not captured and then relies on what the reference variable was initialized to) then enters the while loop which first gets the input from the user to the last question then prints the question again.

```
System.out.print("Would you like to continue (Y/N)?"); //prints to screen
//no input captured before test
while (!Anwser.equals("Y")){ //tests the reference variable
   Anwser = UserInput.next(); //captures user input after test
   System.out.println("Would you like to continue (Y/N)?"); //asks question again
   }
```

The while loop is a a pre-test loop, meaning that it tests the condition before running the code inside. With this code, you're testing the response to the first question to answer the second. So, all you would really need to do if you wanted to keep the while loop is put the question once inside the loop and like so:

```
while (!Anwser.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
{    
   System.out.println("Would you like to continue (Y/N)?");
   Anwser = UserInput.next();
}
```

Also, since you're just capturing a character, maybe instead of making a String object to hold a character literal, try a char variable. Here is that solution:

```
char answer = ' ';    
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

while (answer != 'N') // check for N to end
{           
   System.out.println("Would you like to continue (Y/N)?");
   answer = Character.toUpperCase(userInput.nextLine().charAt(0));
}
```